# Fermion field quantisation in spherical flat spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, fermions

I need any article or paper regarding fermion field quantization in spherical coordinate flat spacetime [in 3+1 dimensions, $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$].

Comment: Can you add context and be more specific?

Comment: From Dirac equation obtaining fermion field operator  in spherical polar coordinate flatspacetime.

Comment: For metric $g_{\mu\nu}=diag(-1,1,r^2,r^2\sin^2\theta)$